# Не сохраняются данные в массив

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Я совсем недавно начал изучать SwiftUI и не могу разобраться.
У меня есть экран с поездками, они находятся в массиве в отдельном файле.
Так же есть экран добавление поездки, там есть кнопка add, после нажатия данные не сохраняются в массив, но .dissmis отрабатывает и закрывает окно.

Массив поездок:

```
class TripsArray : ObservableObject{
    @Published var trip = [
        Trip(country: "South Korea", city: "Seoul", flight: [ Flight(flight_number: "SU123")]),
        Trip(country: "Russia", city: "Moscow", flight: [Flight(flight_number: "SU456")] )
    ]
}

struct Trip: Identifiable{
    var country : String
    var city : String
    var flight : Array<Flight>
    
    var id = UUID()
    var date = Date()
}
struct Flight: Identifiable{
    var flight_number : String
    var id = UUID()
```

Экран добавления поездки:

```
struct NewTrip: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @EnvironmentObject var data : TripsArray
    
    @State var newTrip : Trip = Trip(country: "", city: "", flight: [Flight(flight_number: "")])
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Form {
                Section("Country") {
                    TextField("Country", text: $newTrip.country)
                }
                Section("City") {
                    TextField("City", text: $newTrip.city)
                }
            }
            .toolbar{
                Button("Add"){
                    data.trip.append(newTrip)
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle("New trip")
        
    }
}
```

не могу понять почему не отрабатывает `data.trip.append(newTrip)`
При этом ошибок в Xcode у меня нет

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка, вы, уже нашли решение за это время.

```
@ObservedObject var data = TripsArray()
```